# Difference between function and polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to know if there is an important difference between functions and polynomials? Because in essence they seem very similar, because of the evaluation homomorphism.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain why you think they seem similar. Most functions cannot be expressed as polynomials.

Comment: But functions from a finite field to itself can be.

Comment: What is "the evaluation homomorphism"?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390260/do-we-really-need-polynomials-in-contrast-to-polynomial-functions?rq=1 @bubba You can look it up online.

Comment: Is the evaluation homomorphism an isomorphism? See?

Answer (score 8):

There's a subtle difference between them. A polynomial is not *a priori* a function, but *can* be used as a function. By definition, a polynomial is just a bunch of numbers strung up next to symbols of the form $x^n$. It is a formal object. For example, let's say  $$p(x)=a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots a_1 x + a_0.$$

Then to say $p(x)$ is zero as a polynomial, *by definition* means that all $a_i$ are zero. It turns out that if you were to consider $p(x)$ as a function, saying $p(a) = 0$ for all real numbers $a$, *also* implies that all $a_i$ must be zero, but now this is not by definition and needs a proof:

Suppose that $p(a)=0$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show $p(x)=0$ *as a polynomial*, so we want to show all $a_i=0$. Now if $p(x)$ were a constant polynomial, then it would have to be the zero constant, so we would be done. If $p(x)$ were not constant, then $p(a)=0$ implies $x-a$ is a a factor of $p(x)$. But $p(x)$ can not have infinitely many factors, so that's a contradiction. Therefore, $p(x)=0$ as a polynomial.

Similarly, if we say $p(x)=q(x)$ as polynomials, we mean all their coefficients are equal. But if we say $p(x)=q(x)$ as functions, that *implies* they are equal as polynomials.

So it turns out that the two notions are compatible, but often when we say $p(x)$ is a polynomial, we really just mean a bunch of numbers written next to powers of $x$.

Comment: Note that the key part here is that for each real polynomial, not every element of $\mathbb{R}$ can be a root of that polynomial because there are infinitely many such elements. Whereas if you're working over a *finite* field $F$, there do exist polynomials like that: namely the multiples of $\prod_{a\in F}(x-a)$. So in this situation, we cannot conclude that two polynomials are equal if the functions they determine are equal (but their difference will have $\prod_{a\in F}(x-a)$ as a factor).

Comment: Take for example the polynomial $X^7-X$ in $\mathbb Z_7[X]$. it's all zero for any element of $\mathbb Z_7$, but is not the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly a formal difference, as explained in Prometheus' answer. But let's ignore that for a while, and think about how general functions differ from those defined by polynomials. Maybe this is what the OP had in mind, anyway.

Also, let's assume that we're talking about real-valued functions defined on some bounded interval. If the function is continuous, then the Weierstrass approximation theorem tells us that it can be approximated uniformly to within any desired tolerance by a polynomial. So, in a sense, such a function is *almost* a polynomial. And, for numerical/computational purposes, it *is* a polynomial (or can be adequately represented as one).

So, looking at things this way, there is a fairly broad set of situations where polynomials and general functions are essentially the same thing. If you're working in more exotic/abstract settings, it's a different story, of course.