# Difference between $f(.)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and $f(x)$ for $x \in\mathbb{Z}_q$

Tags: functions, notation, finite-fields

What is the difference between the two following notations.

1. function $f(.)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ .
2. function $f(x)$ where $x$ takes values from $\mathbb{Z}_q$

I think that both are same. Is there any difference between the two notations?

Comment: It's all notation, they are used to designate the same mathematical object...

Comment: I am making an educated guess that the OP may be interested in the difference between a (formal) polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}_q$ and the polynomial function $f:a\mapsto f(a)$ from $\Bbb{Z}_q$ to itself that it yields. Those two ARE different objects. For example the polynomial $x^q-x$ that has degree $q$, and is thus different from a constant polynomial, yields the constant function zero. See e.g. [this discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/390260/11619) in case that is what's bothering you.

Comment: some context, id est, the book you see this in, would be appropriate.  Notation means whatever the author intends it to mean.