# Show that $1+X^4$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z_p$ for every prime $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that $1+X^4$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z_p$ for every prime $p$.

MY ATTEMPT==>I have used Fermat's theorem for this as $X^{p-1}≡1\bmod p$, then this can also be written in the form $1≡X^{p-1}\bmod p$.
So, in $\mathbb Z_p$, $$1+X^4 =X^{p-1}+X^4 = X(X^3 + X^{p-2})$$ as $p\ge2$,
i.e., $1+X^4 = X(X^3 + X^{p-2})$.

Am I correct?

Comment: but is my approach correct?

Comment: No. It is not correct. The polynomial $X^{p-1}$ is not the same polynomial as the constant $1$, Little Fermat notwithstanding. Two polynomials $p(X)$ and $q(X)$ are equal if all the powers of $X$ have the same coefficients in $p$ and $q$. You may be [confused by the difference between a polynomial and a polynomial function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/390260/11619). You are asked to show that the polynomial $X^4+1$ is a product of two lower degree polynomials.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,you meant to say that we are not sure about the integer nature of X.

Comment: $X$ is a variable. It is not an integer (nor an element of $\Bbb{Z}_p$). It is a formal variable. You can substitute many a thing in place of $X$, but it is "more than the totality of all the possible substitutions". Mind you, this takes some time getting used to. I didn't get used to thinking about it as a formal variable right away myself. Read more about the difference between (formal) polynomials and polynomial functions. A polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ cannot be equated with a function from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to itself. There are only finitely many such functions,

Comment: (cont'd) but infinitely many polynomials. For example $1,X,X^2,\ldots$ are all different polynomials. Among other things they have different degrees.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:now i got it.thanks for help and suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear that!