# Possible misconception of the ring of polynomials over a field F.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

When we let $F$ be a field and we define $R = F[x]$ to be the ring of polynomials where each coefficient is in $F$, how exactly can we talk about divisibility of polynomials? Do we ignore the actual value of the polynomial, and only consider the variable as 'place-holder' for the coefficients? If not, then what do we do about the roots of the denominators?

I guess what I'm trying to get at is whether there's a difference between f(x), the value the polynomial f has at x, and the polynomial f.

Comment: Polynomial division. For any polynomials f(x), p(x), there exists f(x) = p(x)q(x) + r(x). If r(x) = 0, q divides f.

Comment: When discussing divisibility of polynomials we mean divisibility in the ring of (formal) polynomials. Many learners have trouble switching their point of view from that of polynomial functions to that of (formal) polynomials. This is very natural, because world wide we first get exposed to polynomials with real coefficients only, where the distinction doesn't really matter. See [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390260/11619) for more detailed discussion.

Comment: Having said that. I don't really agree with the downvotes here (other than possibly for not searching the site first). This is a very common obstacle for students. I recall not fully appreciating it first myself. Only a course on finite fields forced it down my throat :-)

Comment: The $x$ in a polynomial in abstract algebra is not an unknown or a variable (although we still _call_ it an unknown or a variable, because inventing whole new vocabulary is inconvenient). It is, as you say, a numbered placeholder with certain defined laws of multiplication and addition, and nothing more.

Comment: As an aside, if $f \in F[x]$, you can make sense of evaluating $f$ at an element of any (commutative, associative an with unit) $F$-algebra -- such as $F[x]$ itself. Then if we write $f(x)$ to mean the value of $f$ evaluated at $x \in F[x]$, then you actually have $f = f(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ring theory, one must distinguish between an *(abstract) polynomial* and a *polynomial function*. An (abstract) polynomial in $p \in F[x]$ is (formally) just a map $f : \Bbb N_{0} \to F$ with finite support (all but finitely many of the outputs of $p$ are $0$). Addition of polynomials is standard component-wise addition of functions and multiplication is given by

$$
(p\cdot q)_n = \sum_{k=0}^n p_kq_{n-k}.
$$

Here, $p_n$ is the $n$th *coefficient* of the polynomial $p$. Associated with every polynomial and $\alpha \in F$, there is an *evalutation homomorphism* $\text{eval}_\alpha : F[x] \to F$ defined by

$$
\text{eval}_{\alpha}(p)=\sum_{n=0}^{\deg p} p_n \alpha^n.
$$

($\deg p$ is defined to be the largest $k$ such that $p_k \ne 0$.) A function $f : F \to F$ is called a *polynomial function* if there exists an (abstract) polynomial $p \in F[x]$ such that $f(\alpha) = \text{eval}_\alpha(p)$ for all $\alpha \in F$.

The distinction between polynomial and polynomial function is critical when one moves to finite fields. Consider the (abstract) polynomial $p(x) = 1 + 1\cdot x$ and the polynomial function $f(x) = 1 + x$ for the field $\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$. Then $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ so the function $f$ is equal to the zero function but $p$ is **not** the zero polynomial.

To divisibilty! An (abstract) polynomial $p$ divides a polynomial $g$ if there exists another polynomial $q$ such that $g = p \cdot q$. We don't care if $p$ has zeros. Heck, $p$ could be the example above that is entirely zero *as a polynomial function*. All we care about is that $p$ is not the zero polynomial.

---

**Edit to Address the OP's questions in the comments:** Above I mean $\Bbb N_0 := \{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$--different mathematicians define $\Bbb N$ as either $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ or $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ so I subscript $0$ to indicate I am using the latter definition. By finite support, I mean that, for an (abstract) polynomial $p$, the sequence $p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots$ is eventually all zeros. Formally, there exists an $N \in \Bbb N_0$ such that $p_{m} = 0$ for every $m > N$. The finite support condition is necessary to rule out infinite series like $p(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$. You're absolutely right that an abstract polynomial has no output: it's just a formal sequence of coefficients.

The evaluation homomorphism is the "bridge" between an abstract polynomial and its corresponding polynomial function. If I have the abstract polynomial $p(x) = 1 + x + 2x^2$, the evaluation homomorphism allows me to actually evaluate this polynomial as you would have in high school algebra. (e.g. $\text{eval}_2(p) = 1 + 2 +2\cdot 2^2 = 11$.)

Comment: Thank you! The example made things clearer. So when we're talking about division, gcds, the euclidean algorithm, unique factorizaton and what-not, we're talking about abstract polynomials, not the functions? However, I don't understand the formal definition of an abstract polynomial.. what does N0 and finite support mean? I thought an abstract polynomial doesn't have an 'output' i.e it's just the coefficients we look at attached to each power of x. I don't know what an evaluation homomorphism is either :(

Comment: @John Yes to your first question. All other questions are addressed in the edit. Happy mathing!

Comment: Thank you. Now I don't have to write 'assuming the denominator is not zero' each time I divide.