# Are they regarded as the same polynomial in $F_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $p$ be prime. Let $p_1(x)=x^p-x$, $p_2(x)=0$ be two polynomials in $F_p[x]$. We know that $p_1=p_2$ as functions, by Fermat's little theorem. However, can I say that $p_1(x)$ is the zero polynomial?

Comment: Nope. $p_1$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree $p$ with the leading coefficient $1$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390260/11619) for more discussion about the difference between polynomial functions and (formal) polynomials. In calculus and below students really only encounter polynomial functions. Which is ok because over infinite fields there is no difference. It may be helpful to think that into a polynomial from $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ you can plug-in as $x$, in addition to elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$ also elements of any extension field (elements of any extension ring actually, such as another polynomial, or a matrix with entries in $\Bbb{F}_p$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The elements of a polynomial ring like $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ are polynomials as *formal expressions*, not as functions.  In other words, two polynomials are defined to be the same only when all of their coefficients are the same.  (Or if you prefer, a polynomial is defined to *be* its coefficients: an element of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is technically a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $f(n)=0$ for all but finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  We normally write such a function as the "polynomial expression" $f(0)+f(1)x+f(2)x^2+f(3)x^3+\dots$.)

Answer (score 0):

No. They give the same functions $\Bbb Z_p\to\Bbb Z_p$ (the zero function) but they are *not* the same polynomials.

Comment: Which can be verified by taking the derivative.

Comment: @Gyro You wouldn't need to go that far. Simply the definition of polynomial as a finite linear combination of the formal symbols $x^i$. Different linear combinations are different polynomials, period.

Comment: Yes, but they are not only unique by definition, they work out differently, and I think this is worth to mention.

Comment: Of course, if the two are different by definition, there are well-defined functions with the set of polynomials as domain that take them to different things. Differentiation is such a function with the added bonus that it is useful.