# Factoring $x^{15}−1$ into irreducible polynomials over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Factorize $x^{15}−1$ into irreducible polynomials over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$

The answer is 
$$(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$$
but how would I find this? Please help.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention the degree. it is 4

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/50989/11619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $x^{16}-x\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ has roots precisely equal to the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{16}$, and the subfields of $\mathbb{F}_{16}$ are $\mathbb{F}_{16}$, $\mathbb{F}_{4}$, and $\mathbb{F}_{2}$, which have degrees
$$[\mathbb{F}_{16}:\mathbb{F}_2]=4\qquad [\mathbb{F}_{4}:\mathbb{F}_2]=2\qquad [\mathbb{F}_{2}:\mathbb{F}_2]=1$$
Therefore $x^{16}-x$ is the product of the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ of degrees $1$, $2$, and $4$.

Therefore $x^{15}-1$ is the product of the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ of degrees $1$, $2$, and $4$, other than the irreducible polynomial $x$.

To find these irreducible polynomials, you can use Sieve of Eratosthenes ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)), adapted to the ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

Comment: thanks for the reply, very good explanation about finding the degree of the irreducible polynomials for a specific polynomial over GF(q)

Comment: I didn't understand how to find the irreducible polynomials from Sieve of Eratosthenes. Could you explain how to do this please?