# Splitting Field of the polynomial $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Tags: finite-fields, splitting-field

What is the splitting field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of the polynomial $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$?
I already knew the polynomial $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible and its roots are distinct in some extension field of $\mathbb{F}_2$. However, I am not sure if the splitting field must be of the form $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ and if the polynomial $x^4+x+1$ must be a divisor of $x^{2^k}-x$.
Note: I am new to field extension and I haven't learnt about the degree of field extension, so please provide explanation without using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splitting field of this polynomial is
$$
K=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^4+x+1\rangle.
$$
This follows from your observation that $p(x)=x^4+x+1$ is irreducible, and from the fact that if $\gamma=x+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$ is a zero of that polynomial, then

- The other zeros of $p(x)$ are $\gamma^2$, $\gamma^4$, and $\gamma^8=\sqrt\gamma$, so $p(x)$ splits into linear factors over $K$ and
- All the non-zero elements of $K$ are actually powers of $\gamma$, so no smaller field will do.

These facts can be seen from the first principles as follows:

- We know $p(\gamma)=\gamma^4+\gamma+1=0$. Squaring this equation using the binomial formula and the fact that $2=0$ in $K$ we get
  $$0=\gamma^8+\gamma^2+1+2\cdot\text{something}=\gamma^8+\gamma^2+1=p(\gamma^2).$$ Repeating this shows that $\gamma^4$ and $\gamma^8$ are also zeros of $p(x)$. This trick is often facetiously called *freshman's dream*, because we have all met beginners who want to square binomials like $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ - a formula that only works in a commutative ring of characteristic two.
- The other fact I did [as the mid section of this answer I prepared for referrals like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619). You see that I denote the field $K$ by $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ there.

---

Remarks (and/or extras)

- The second part could, indeed, be more easily deduced using basic facts about degrees of field extensions. Because $p(x)$ has degree four, we can deduce that $K$ is a four-dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_2$.
- That freshman's dream -trick works over all finite fields. It implies that adjoining a single root of an irreducible polynomial always automatically gives the other roots as well. This fact is special to finite fields. You have surely seen examples of irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{Q}$ where this does not happen. $x^3-2$ is the standard example of this phenomenon. The same fact can be rephrased as *All finite extensions of finite fields are Galois extensions.* But it sounds like you may not have heard of the concept of a Galois extension yet.
- We have, indeed, that $p(x)\mid x^{16}+x$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50989/11619) for the other factors and a few more details.

Comment: Do you mean, $F(\gamma)\subseteq K$ because $F(\gamma)$ is a splitting field and  $K\subseteq F(\gamma)$ since any element of K is a power of $\gamma$ so $F(\gamma)=K$?

Comment: More like: $K=\Bbb{F}_2(\gamma)$, so $K$ must be contained in the splitting field. And the splitting field is contained in $K$ because $K$ contains all four zeros of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

you are right about the form of the polynomial and the size of the field. let $a$ be a root of $x^4+x+1$ and find its multiplicative order. you get $a,a^2,a^3,a^4=a+1,a^5=a^2+a,\ldots,a^{15}=1.$ so theorder is 15, all these elements are distinct and thus $F_{2^4}$ is the splitting field.