# How to factor this polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

On page 587 in Dummit and Foote, the authors say the polynomial $\frac{x^{16}-x}{x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$ can be factored into quartics over $\mathbb{F}_2$ as $(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)(x^4+x+1)$.

I am having trouble seeing this. When I divide the polynomial $x^{16}-x$ by $x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ using long division, I get $x^{12}+x^9+x^6+x^3+1$. However, I am not sure how to factor this polynomial into quartics. How do I do this?

Comment: You could try every possible quartic. You could use a systematic method, such as Berlekamp's algorithm. You could multiply the given factors to see if they work.

Comment: There are only three irreducible quartics over $\Bbb F_2$, namely $X^4+X+1$, $X^4+X^3+1$, and $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{F}_p$ we always have that $x^{p^n}-x$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials of degrees that are factors of $n$. You already listed all the irreducible linear and quadratics, so the remaining factors are all the irreducible quartics, listed by Lubin.

Comment: This is also close to being a duplicate of [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50989/11619), but I honestly wonder why that was so highly voted.

Answer (score 2):

The Berlekamp algorithm gives
$$
x^{16}-x=(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + 1)(x^4 + x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x + 1)x.
$$
So the statement in Dummit and Foote is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Over $\mathbb Z$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
x^{16}-x &= x(x^{15}-1)
\\&= x \Phi_1(x) \Phi_3(x) \Phi_5(x) \Phi_{15}(x)
\\&= x (x - 1) (x^2 + x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1)
\end{align}
$$
and so your polynomial is $(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1)$.

You only need to factor $(x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1)$ mod $2$.